# Set Timezone to 00:00, datetime.now() but only date

Tags: python, django, datetime

My code:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
dt_now = datetime.now(timezone)
today = datetime(dt_now.year, dt_now.month, dt_now.day, tzinfo=timezone)
print(today)
```

The result is = 2020-08-14 00:00:00-00:01

Expected: **2020-08-14 00:00:00-00:00**

TY

Comment: Can reproduce, it might have something to do with the timezone, if you print that you get `<DstTzInfo 'Europe/London' LMT-1 day, 23:59:00 STD>` (note the "23:59:00")

Comment: >>> import pytz
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
>>> dt_now = datetime.now(timezone)
>>> today = datetime(dt_now.year, dt_now.month, dt_now.day, tzinfo=timezone)
>>> print(today)
2020-08-14 00:00:00-00:01

Comment: but I need 2020-08-14 00:00:00-00:00; any idea plz?

Comment: solved: timezone = pytz.timezone('UTC')

Comment: you don't need `pytz` to set UTC, just use `datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)`